# Doom Emacs slow startup and flickering on Windows 10

Tags: windows, performance, emacs, flicker

I am running doom emacs v2.0.9 on windows 10; and my window (not the whole emacs frame) flickers when I navigate up or down (note: not left and right). This is annoying. Also startup time is anywhere between 20 to 40 seconds on first startup, and later boots take around 5 to 15 seconds. How do I fix this?

Comment: My startup is find (SSD), but the automatic linters in some languages and intense scrolling can really slow it down for me. The slow startup may be do with packages loaded in on launch. Did you make any progress since posting this?